# SWIFT OS X - deleting managed objects from persistent store: fatal error

Tags: macos, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am using the function below to delete managed objects from a persistent store. 
The deletion function is:

```
 func deletePPRRowDataManagedObject(date: NSDate) {

    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(self.pprRowEntity, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! PPRRowData
    var pprRowDataArray = self.fetchPPRRowDataManagedObjects()
    let filteredPPRRowDataArray = pprRowDataArray.filter({$0.pprDate == date})
    for object in filteredPPRRowDataArray {

        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(object)
    }

    var pprFileDataArray =  self.fetchPPRFileDataManagedObjects()
    let filteredPPRFileDataArray = pprFileDataArray.filter({$0.pprDate == date})
    for object in filteredPPRFileDataArray {

        managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(object)
    }

    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&error) {

        //  this code needs to be replaced to properly deal with the error
        abort()
    }
}
```

I have three subclassed Core Data entities of which I am trying to delete managed objects from the persistent store for two them in this code.

There are no relationships defined between the three entities.  All three are saved within the same managed object context and the same persistent store.

After I have deleted the managed objects I can create and fetch data from the persistent store without a runtime error.  I can access data from the third entity but now get a data fault when i try to access the data arrays created from the fetch..... functions that source the managed objects from the persistent store for the two entities that I have deleted some managed objects for.

The code (below) to fetch the data from the persistent store runs without error.  The error

> (EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error)

occurs when I try to access the outputArray.

```
     let outputArray = addDataFiles.fetchPPRRowDataManagedObjects()
```

When I run the code prior to any deletions it runs without any problems.

Any thoughts/guidance on what may be creating the error would be appreciated.  I have not been able to determine if it is a problem with the code I am using to delete the managed objects or the relevant fetch... function that I am using.

The following is an example of one of the fetch... functions that I am using:

```
func fetchPPRRowDataManagedObjects() ->Array<PPRRowData>{

    let fetchRequestPPRRowData = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityPPRRowData = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(self.pprRowEntity, inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    var resultsArrayPPRRowData: Array<PPRRowData> = []
    var arrayFetchResults: Array<AnyObject> = []
    fetchRequestPPRRowData.entity = entityPPRRowData
    var error: NSError? = nil
    arrayFetchResults = managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequestPPRRowData, error: &error)!
    for index in arrayFetchResults {

        resultsArrayPPRRowData.append(index as! PPRRowData)
    }
    return resultsArrayPPRRowData
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error?  Also when you fetch you are not looking at that error at all.  Quite possible you are getting an error on your fetch and not handling it.

Comment: You are also not printing out the error on a failed save.  At least calling `print("Error: \(error)")` will let you know that *something* happened.

Comment: I have included the error code suggested.  I do not get an error thrown on save for either fetch.. or delete..  The only thing that happens is that I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error when i try and access the outputArray after some of the managed objects have been deleted.

Comment: Which array are you referring to as the output array?  Are you trying to access an object that was previously deleted?

Comment: the deletePPR..... function above is supposed to filter out and then delete only some of the managed objects.  Having called that function I then call the fetchPPR... function shown above and return the resultsArrayPRRowData to outputArray as per the let statement included in the text above.  It is after that when I access the outputArray in a for-in loop that i get the bad access error.  If I have not deleted anything the access code works fine and I can access outputArray without any issues.

Comment: Another couple of observations - there is no error when I run the fetchPPR... function.  I can successfully run `let indexes = outputArray.count` and it returns the correct number.  I guess this means that the managed objects contained within the array are corrupted somehow in the deletion process?

Comment: I would remove the for loop in your delete.  It is completely unnecessary and can be causing you issues since Swift is pass by value and not pass by reference.  However I would expect that to cause you an issue every time and not just after a delete.  Nevertheless, that loop is redundant.  Just cast the array that is returned from `executeFetchRequest` properly.

Comment: I don't see how this would work - the for loop iterates over an array of managed objects.  I can't use `.deleteObject` on the array.  I may have misunderstood what you suggested?

Comment: `.executeFetchRequest()` returns `[PPRRowData]` back, you just need to cast correct on **that** line.  The for loop doesn't do anything but create a new array and since Swift passes by value and the `arrayFetchResults` is a special subclass from Core Data you are potentially causing the issue by doing that second array iteration.  Best to remove it to be sure.

Comment: Marcus - I have previously tried that but I get a "cannot assign a value of type..." error if I add `as! PPRRowData` to the `.executeFetchRequest()` line.  That is why I ended up with the `for index..` loop.

Comment: `as! PPRRowData` is not the same thing as `as! [PPRRowData]` which tells swift that it is an **array** of PPRRowData instances.  A completely different thing.

Comment: Sorry - now I understand - new to this thing. I have made the suggested changes to the .executeFetch statements but no change in the error. I have also played quite a bit with the code trying to isolate where the BAD-ACCESS error is occurring. It appears that I can add new Managed Objects, fetch them and use them but whenever I either delete or update their value i then get the BAD_ACCESS error in one of the arrays.

Comment: Ok - after a lot of code testing, I have identified the problem was an erroneous `!managedObjectContext!.save()` statement that was firing part way through the code.  Not even sure why it was there but it was obviously creating the problem.  Marcus, many thanks for your patience and suggestions, it led to me reviewing my code more closely and eventually identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - after a lot of code testing, I have identified the problem was an erroneous !managedObjectContext!.save() statement that was firing within the loop as I was iterating through the code - both in the createManagedObject() function and in the .deleteManagedObject() function that I had created. Not even sure why it was there (that is, why I had put it there in the first place) but it was obviously creating the problem.

Marcus, many thanks for your patience and suggestions, it led to me reviewing my code more closely and eventually identifying the problem. –  Wolfstar 1 hour ago